# How to make screenshot using C# & XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

How to make screenshot and save it to HDD using C# & XNA, while running game in fullscreen mode?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775196/take-screen-shot-in-xna

Comment: But, I want to make it while running and I don't have anything like 'ResolveTexture2D', and save it, not print.

Comment: This question is **not a duplicate** (of that one anyway). The API changed in XNA 4.0 and the answer there is not applicable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The API was [changed in XNA 4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/30/resolvebackbuffer-and-resolvetexture2d-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx).

If you are running on the `HiDef` profile (Xbox 360 and newer Windows machines), you can use `GraphicsDevice.GetBackBufferData`.

To make saving that data easy, you could use put the output from that into a `Texture2D.SetData` and then use `SaveAsPng` or `SaveAsJpeg` (this is slightly slower than it needs to be, because it also sends the data back to the GPU - but it is just so *easy*).

If you are using the `Reach` profile, then you have to render your scene to a `RenderTarget2D`. My [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616232/xna-to-render-3d-video-fixed-fps/3617759#3617759) should give you a good starting point.

Comment: How to make that if I am using GraphicsDeviceManager? ( I'm beginner, sorry for such a stupid question :) )

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Are you looking for `GraphicsDeviceManager.GraphicsDevice`? You should [check MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphicsdevicemanager_members.aspx) for these things. Of course, if you are in a class derived from `Game` or `GameComponent`, they have [`GraphicsDevice` properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game_members.aspx) you can access directly.

Answer (score 4):

Here take a look at this code.

```
count += 1;
string counter = count.ToString();

int w = GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth;
int h = GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight;

//force a frame to be drawn (otherwise back buffer is empty) 
Draw(new GameTime());

//pull the picture from the buffer 
int[] backBuffer = new int[w * h];
GraphicsDevice.GetBackBufferData(backBuffer);

//copy into a texture 
Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, w, h, false, GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferFormat);
texture.SetData(backBuffer);

//save to disk 
Stream stream = File.OpenWrite(counter + ".jpg");

texture.SaveAsJpeg(stream, w, h);
stream.Dispose();

texture.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616232/xna-to-render-3d-video-fixed-fps) shows you how to take a screenshot.  In this example, it is saving an image every render, so you just need to move it to a function that you can call when you want to save the screenshot.