# XNA Graphics Device for creating a JPG image

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xna, rendering

I'd like to write some unit tests that produce JPG images.  I'm working on a game using XNA and want to have some rendering tests I can run and visually inspect that I haven't broken anything etc.

I have a Unit Test project that calls into my code to generate XNA objects like Triangle Strips, but all the rendering examples seem to assume I have a Game object and am rendering to the associated GraphicsDevice which is a window on the screen.

If possible, I'd like to render in memory and just save JPG images that I can inspect after the tests finish running.  Alternatively, I guess I could instantiate a Game object in the unit tests, render to the screen and then dump to a JPG as described here: [How to make screenshot using C# & XNA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529815/how-to-make-screenshot-using-c-sharp-xna/8064025#8064025)

But that doesn't sound very efficient.

So, put simply, is there a way to instantiate a GraphicsDevice object outside of an XNA Game that writes to a buffer in memory?

Comment: I tried instantiating a new GraphicsDevice using its only constructor and it throws an exception saying "PresentationParameters.DeviceWindowHandle" must not be null.  Should I try constructing a window just for rendering, or is there some other approach?

Comment: I added System.Windows.Forms to my Unit Test project and instantiated a Control object.  Now when I try to get the back-buffer data to grab the screenshot, I get this exception: XNA Framework Reach profile does not support GetBackBufferData

Comment: You can create the graphics device with the `HiDef` profile if you want to use `GetBackBufferData()`.  A better way to take screenshots, though, is to write your code in such a way that it can output to a render target instead of the back buffer, and then save that render target using its `SaveAsJpeg()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up instantiating a Control object from System.Windows.Forms.  I made this part of my Unit Test project so my game doesn't depend on Windows Forms.

This is the class I use to provide functionality to produce JPGs for my tests:

```
public class JPGGraphicsDeviceProvider
{
    private Control _c;
    private RenderTarget2D _renderTarget;
    private int _width;
    private int _height;

    public JPGGraphicsDeviceProvider(int width, int height)
    {
        _width = width;
        _height = height;
        _c = new Control();

        PresentationParameters parameters = new PresentationParameters()
        {
            BackBufferWidth = width,
            BackBufferHeight = height,
            BackBufferFormat = SurfaceFormat.Color,
            DepthStencilFormat = DepthFormat.Depth24,
            DeviceWindowHandle = _c.Handle,
            PresentationInterval = PresentInterval.Immediate,
            IsFullScreen = false,
        };

        GraphicsDevice = new GraphicsDevice(GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter,
                                            GraphicsProfile.Reach,
                                            parameters);

        // Got this idea from here: http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/67895.aspx
        _renderTarget = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice,
            GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth,
            GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight);

        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(_renderTarget);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current graphics device.
    /// </summary>
    public GraphicsDevice GraphicsDevice { get; private set; }

    public void SaveCurrentImage(string jpgFilename)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
        int w = GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth;
        int h = GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight;

        using (Stream stream = new FileStream(jpgFilename, FileMode.Create))
        {
            _renderTarget.SaveAsJpeg(stream, w, h);
        }
        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(_renderTarget);
    }
}
```

Then in my tests, I just instantiate this and use the GraphicsDevice provided:

```
[TestClass]
public class RenderTests
{
    private JPGGraphicsDeviceProvider _jpgDevice;
    private RenderPanel _renderPanel;
    public RenderTests()
    {
        _jpgDevice = new JPGGraphicsDeviceProvider(512, 360);
        _renderPanel = new RenderPanel(_jpgDevice.GraphicsDevice);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void InstantiatePrism6()
    {
        ColorPrism p = new ColorPrism(6, Color.RoyalBlue, Color.Pink);

        _renderPanel.Add(p);
        _renderPanel.Draw();

        _jpgDevice.SaveCurrentImage("six-Prism.jpg");
    }
}
```

I'm sure it's not bug-free, but it seems to work for now.